# vis.js network graph testing using selenium

Tags: selenium, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am looking for solution to test network graph implemented using vis.js. I am using selenium with nightwatch.js for writing tests. But I am clueless that how to locate the graph and test events like select nodes and edges, node double click, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Found](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/1827#issuecomment-215052400) the solution within Selenium APIs. Only the thing we must know is X and Y offset for any node, we are interested in. Below is the code snippet:

```
'Click on Graph Node' : function(browser) {
      browser
          .moveTo(GRAPH_CANVAS_XPATH, 5, 198)
          .click(GRAPH_CANVAS_XPATH)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. How would you go about getting the coordinates of the node though? IOW, how would you get the current dataset (of VisJs) within your test modules, in order to find the particular node you're looking for?